# Can one Teemo mushroom get a penta kill?

Tags: league-of-legends

If a team-fight got the entire enemy team to low health, and all went together into a Teemo-shroom, can that one shroom get a penta-kill?

Comment: Hi @Jesse, your question was closed as Not A Real Question because it is simply "I'm wondering if this can happen." Our FAQ states `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face`. Questions designed to elicit discussion are not appropriate for our site, as we are a Q&A site, not a forum.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes, but it would be very hard to pull it off.

Answer (score 1):

With the situation that you just described it is possible, but the chances of all of them in the 1 small group to land in one mushroom is unlikely. Going pure AP with the 5 AAs (Arch Angel's Staffs) and Rabadon's Death Cap Teemo's Shroom should do tons of damage, but that is a highly unlikely build and would only be used for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If the situation occurs as you describe, and Teemo is on full ap build, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

If it hits everyone he can get a penta, even shacos box should be able to get penta if everyone is that low and they don't kill the box

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be done, but it's gonna be one of those "one-in-a-million" when all the stars are aligned, with a full AP build and the enemies with kinda low HP.

When i've been playing AP Teemo late game, my shrooms do about 1200 dmg so the enemies doesn't really have to be extremely low on HP.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Teemo_the_Swift_Scout)

> **Noxious Trap** (Active): Teemo places a trap which stealths and arms after 1 second. It detonates if an enemy steps on it, **poisoning all
>   enemies nearby to be dealt magic damage every second for 4 seconds**
>   plus slowing them and providing vision of them (doesn't reveal
>   stealthed units) for 4 seconds. This poison will not stack but the
>   duration will be refreshed with every subsequent detonation. Mushrooms
>   have 100 health and can be destroyed by autoattacks if they are
>   visible, but they are immune to spell damage. The traps last 10
>   minutes. Teemo will store one every several seconds, the charge time
>   will be affected by cooldown reduction, and can have a maximum of
>   three stocked up. Each cast requires and uses a trap. Range: 230
>   Cooldown: 1 second Activation Radius: 120 (estimate) Explosion Radius:
>   400 (estimate) Sight Radius: 425 (estimate)

As you can see, one mushroom will poison ALL the enemies without damage reduction for multiple target.

> Magic Damage per Second: 50 / 100 / 150 (+0.2 per ability power)
>
> Total Magic Damage: 200 / 400 / 600 (+0.8 per ability power)

If you follow this:

you can kill all enemies **if** they all got hit by Noxious trap, **and** they all are very low on health **and** they all don't have good magic resistance.

Helps if you are Teemo AP.

But there is too many IF's in this to make it count, so it is VERY unlikable to happen.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, especially if is an AP Teemo... tons of damage.